# Synchronous XMLHttpRequest Error for getting xml

Tags: jquery, xml, xmlhttprequest, load

I am trying to get xml data from openweathermap.org. So I get url something like this: "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&mode=xml" (this one is for test) result of this is xml data of weather. So url works for me fine.

I whant to create small web app that shows me weater for my town. So first, I do this to get xml:

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

xmlhttp.open("GET","http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&mode=xml", false); //here i get error notice
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 

var firstRow = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('temperature');
```

This works fine **but** I am getting error message in row **xmlhttp.open**. Message is this:

**Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwq.org/**

Now this couse problem that sometimes xml that I am requesting is not loaded (so my data is empty). Then I also check it with debbuger and in cases like this, xmlhttp.open is underline (with above message), and xmlhttp.send(), where error is empty request. Then I refresh couple times, and it get data.

Any idea what is this error message, how to fix it? Tnx for help

Comment: Since you are using jquery, by the tag you gave to your post, why not use jquery's ajax API instead?  In that case, you can use async call and have a callback that is invoked with the request is complete, with the callback doing whatever processing you need on the data.

Comment: What part of this message do you not understand?  The 3rd argument to `xmlhttp.open()` needs to be `true` to use an async `XMLHttpRequest` and avoid this message.  And, then you need to code for an async response instead of a synchronous response.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started#Step_3_.E2.80.93_A_Simple_Example for a working example.  But, as ewh said, it would be much simpler to use jQuery's Ajax support.

Comment: @ewh thx for advice, can you check my answer that I post, If is this possible solution? Realy thx for help

Answer (score 0):

With help of ajax API basicaly I did this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://api.openweathermap.org...",
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'xml',
}).done(function(data){
  xmlDoc = data;
});
```

Now this seems to work (no error message), xmlDoc have now (when debugg) same data as before, when I used xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;

Comment: if you are getting what you expect, I guess it works :)